# wget error 400 from PHP, 200 from command line

Tags: php, wget

From the command line (via SSH on my server) this works:

```
wget "https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD"
```

from PHP on the same server:

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD";
exec("/usr/bin/wget $url");
```

I get:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2018-11-07 15:01:21 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Why are you using exec/wget instead of something like curl? I'm going to guess that it's because the url inside of exec is not quoted like it is on the command line. You'd have to add quotes

Comment: @aynber - [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) is the preferred way to do it.  Otherwise, it'd say that's a good possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, what's different between the two?

```
wget "https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD"
```

VS

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD";
exec("/usr/bin/wget $url");
```

Let's take your PHP code :
If you print echo `$url` you will get :

```
https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD
```

Literally.

So, what's going on in your exec call then?
if you echo `"/usr/bin/wget $url"` you will get :

```
/usr/bin/wget https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD
```

Literally.
Now what's the difference between

```
wget "https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD"
```

and

```
/usr/bin/wget https://www.example.com/script?paramA=1234&paramB=ABCD
```

Of course there is the path : `/usr/bin` but... If you try it out, you'll find that's not your problem...

What else ? The quotes.  The url in your shell command is wrapped in quotes, while it's not, in the one generated by your PHP code.

As mentioned by @ArtisticPhoenix in the comments, you can use the php function `escapeshellarg()` on your $url variable. It will add the quotes around your url (and also make sure that your string stays a string, to prevent injection, for example) and your command should run fine.

If you want to know what's happening here, it's that the `&` symbol in your url is parsed by the console that execute two commands instead of just one. Your url call (With `paramB` missing and another command `paramB=ABCD` that creates a variable in your shell. You can see it by typing `echo $paramB` that will print ABCD in your console. The API you are calling probably relies on `paramB` to be present, therefore, returning you a 400 error.

Hope this helps. Good luck.